# How to acces methods/properties of usercontrol class through panel in main form in C# winForm

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, panel

In my project, I created  usercontrol which has property. This userControl is added in Panel control in main form. I want this property value in main form button click event.

User Control class Code:

```
  public partial class uc_protectionTbl1 : UserControl
  {
     public string obsValue { get; set; }
  }
```

Main Form class code :

```
  public partial class MainForm : Form
  {

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        addUserControl();
    }
    private void addUserControl()
    {
       uc_protectionTbl1 objUC = new uc_protectionTbl1();
       panelUC.Controls.Add(objUC);
    }
    private void SavetoolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //Here I want this property value     
    }
```

I tried using foreach loop to get controls from panel but how to get property value?

I tried this

```
     private void SavetoolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        string testValue;    

        foreach (Control p in panelUC.Controls)
        {  
            if (p is uc_protectionTbl1) 
            { 
               testValue =       //test value is the value from property
            }
        }
     }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *I tried using foreach loop to get controls from panel* can you show that?

Comment: You have a couple of options: • Set its `Name` and find it by name in the parent `(uc_protectionTbl1)panelUC.Controls["someName"]` • Define `objUC` as a class member field, then you have access to the member in other methods as well. • Find it using `(uc_protectionTbl1)panelUC.Controls[0]` • Find it by its type, `panelUC.Controls.OfType<uc_protectionTbl1>().FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: I added  code which I tried, please see my edited question.

Comment: What about this: `testValue = ((uc_protectionTbl1)p).obsValue;`?

Comment: Thank you so much to all for your time. All the answers are correct. but I used this : testValue = ((uc_protectionTbl1)p).obsValue;

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ to get a strongly typed reference to your control:

```
var myControl = panelUC.Controls.OfType<uc_protectionTbl1>().FirstOrDefault();
string testValue = myControl?.obsValue;
```

Note that `testValue` could be `null` - you should check it.

I would also suggest you to use the C# code style, where all types and methods use `PascalCase` (i.e. start with a capital letter).